# Call proceed with n parameters in AspectJ

Tags: java, parameters, aop, aspectj

assuming that i defined a pointcut of this form

```
* *.*(..)
```

and i want to define an around advice, how can i call proceed with an arbitrary number of parameters?

I thought about using reflection and thisJoinPoint.getArgs() but before trying, i would like to know if there's a clean and easy way.

Comment: @LihO, while "advice" might be an AOP-specific term, the tag as-is is going to be abused by people that come here for "advice."  If you must insist on the tag existing, please either actively police it or find another way to express the idea that won't be abused by clueless taggers.  The type of people that will abuse the tag are not the type that read and understand tag wiki excerpts telling them not to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common misunderstanding that `proceed` takes the same arguments as the method that matches the pattern does. However, `proceed` takes arguments that ***advice*** prescribes.

Example:

```
class C {   
    public void foo(int i, int j, char c) {
        System.out.println("T.foo() " + i*j + " " + c);
    }
}

class Context {
    public int bar = 7;
    public void doStuff() {
        C c = new C();
        c.foo(2, 3, 'x');
    }
}
```

with an aspect:

```
public aspect MyAspect {

    pointcut AnyCall() : 
        call(* *.*(..)) && !within(MyAspect);

    void around(Context c) : AnyCall() && this(c) {
        if (c.bar > 5)
            proceed(c);  // based on "around(Context c)"
    }       
}
```